# Sharing Laravel Auth::check() not working on subpages

Tags: laravel-5

I am sharing the laravel session across subdomains. It is working on the main page but not on any inner pages.

Example:

**sub1.example.com** = Logged into laravel

**sub2.example.com** = Shows logged in on the home page but not inner pages.

I have my session domain set correctly but it's not working.
'domain' => '.example.com'

I cleared cookies in browser.

**Update**

After removing / from my app url it has been resloved.

Comment: Are you sure you've provided middleware to the routes or in the construct method ? public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

Comment: I think we don't need to do it manually, once laravel authenticate(Logged in) it takes care of maintaining session until it's all flushed by logout.

Comment: The issue is on the non laravel site. I added the vendor autoload files to sub2 so I can do the Auth::check() so I can show a user dropdown if they are logged into sub1. It works on the sub2 homepage but not inner pages.

Comment: Not sure why but removing the trailing slash from my app URL fixed the issue.

Comment: If you resolved your issue all by yourself then please update the answer just in case if someone have problem same as yours.